# How to make error message to display for that particular input field using angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have multiple input fields, adding and changing are working fine with that particular fieds, but when coming to error message section, if there is input field eror in one field it is shown in all other fields. But, i want error to display for that particular field.

HTML:

```
<md-card-content>
  <ul class="listClass">
    <li *ngFor="let media of videos; let i = index ">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="{{media._id}}[i]" id="{{media._id}}[i]" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" [(ngModel)]="media.editText" #editText pattern="/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ ]+$/" style="width: 58%;margin-left: 1%;">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="errorMsg" style="color:red">
        {{errorMsg}}
      </div>
      <p class="inputimg" style="float: right;display: inline-block">
        <label *ngIf="media._id" class="img_change" (click)="change($event,media)" style="width: 100px;">Change Link</label>
        <label *ngIf="!media._id" class="img_change" (click)="changetext($event,media)" >Add Link</label>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</md-card-content>
```

TS:

```
    change(event: any, media) {
    if (media.editText.indexOf('https://www.youtube.com/embed') != -1) {
      this.errorMsg="";
      if (!media._id) {
        var data:any = {
          pin_id: this.pin_id,
          media_type: "video",
          image_path: media.editText
        } 
        this.ApiService
            .addLinkMedia(data)
            .subscribe(
              media => {
              })
      } else if(media._id) {
        var data:any = {
          media_id: media._id,
          image_path: media.editText
        } 
        this.ApiService
            .addLinkMedia(data)
            .subscribe(
              media => {
                this.loadMedias()
              }, error => {
              })
      }
    } else {
      this.errorMsg = "Please enter valid URL";
    }
}
```

here i havent used any form validations.

Comment: Can you show some more code of your html where your other input fields are or how it looks when the error is displayed. If you have the `*ngIf="errorMsg" under every field then of cause it will show on all, you'd have to use a different variable for every field or at least an array, or better angulars default form validation tools.

Comment: can you make working example of what you have done

Comment: This is the only input field i have for giving video link

Comment: are you using ng-repeat?

Comment: @Sravan No, only so much code i have used

Comment: then what is that `[i]` in your question. you must be having `ng-repeat` above that

Comment: @Sravan `*ngFor` not `ng-repeat` this does not seem to be angularjs

Comment: I have used *ngFor, and i have updated my question with still more codes

Comment: yeah yeah `*ngFor` m still in `angular1` mood.

Comment: Thats ok chill, have any idea?

Comment: @Sravan Genius man, working like a charm, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a variable, which stores the `id` of `media` and **display error message accordingly depending on the media ID**.

- I m assigning **`this.errorDiv[media._id] = true;;`** so that I can use
  `errorDiv` in *ngIf
- In HTML I used **`*ngIf="errorMsg[media._id] && (errorDiv[media._id])"`** which checks the error message and specific Id and display error message accordingly

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="{{media._id}}[i]" id="{{media._id}}[i]" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" [(ngModel)]="media.editText" #editText pattern="/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ ]+$/" style="width: 58%;margin-left: 1%;">
</div>
<div *ngIf="errorMsg[media._id] && (errorDiv[media._id])" style="color:red">
    {{errorMsg[media._id]}}
</div>
<p >
    <label *ngIf="media._id" (click)="change($event,media)">Change Link</label>
    <label *ngIf="!media._id" (click)="change($event,media)">Add Link</label>
</p>
```

**Component:**

```
public errorDiv = {};
public errorMsg = {};


    change(event: any, media) {
        if (media.editText.indexOf('https://www.youtube.com/embed') != -1) {
          this.errorMsg[media._id] = "";
          this.errorDiv[media._id] = "";
          if (!media._id) {
            var data:any = {
              pin_id: this.pin_id,
              media_type: "video",
              image_path: media.editText
            }
            this.ApiService
                .addLinkMedia(data)
                .subscribe(
                  media => {
                  })
          } else if(media._id) {
            var data:any = {
              media_id: media._id,
              image_path: media.editText
            }
            this.ApiService
                .addLinkMedia(data)
                .subscribe(
                  media => {
                    this.loadMedias()
                  }, error => {
                  })
          }
        } else {
          this.errorMsg[media._id] = "Please enter valid URL";
          this.errorDiv[media._id] = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if you enter a invalid url into 2 fields? Then the error message will be displayed only on the latest.

Comment: but if you see there is submit button on Individual fields, but not all at once since they are wrapped inside `*ngFor`

Comment: It's not very probably yea, but still if you enter an invalid url without submitting and then switch to another input field entering an invalid url again then the error message will only be displayed on the 2nd field.

Comment: @Fussel, now I fulfilled that requirement by changing the variable to object and assigning removing the `errorMesage` for particular media.

Comment: @SravanYour previous answer was working fine, in this i am unable to get error message, can you please post the previous one itself

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the error message to each media object separately:

HTML:

```
<md-card-content>
  <ul class="listClass">
    <li *ngFor="let media of videos; let i = index ">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="{{media._id}}[i]" id="{{media._id}}[i]" class="form-control form-textbox input-text" [(ngModel)]="media.editText" #editText pattern="/^(ftp|http|https):\/\/[^ ]+$/" style="width: 58%;margin-left: 1%;">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="media.errorMsg" style="color:red">
        {{media.errorMsg}}
      </div>
      <p class="inputimg" style="float: right;display: inline-block">
        <label *ngIf="media._id" class="img_change" (click)="change($event,media)" style="width: 100px;">Change Link</label>
        <label *ngIf="!media._id" class="img_change" (click)="changetext($event,media)" >Add Link</label>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</md-card-content>
```

TS:

```
    change(event: any, media) {
    if (media.editText.indexOf('https://www.youtube.com/embed') != -1) {
      media.errorMsg="";
      if (!media._id) {
        var data:any = {
          pin_id: this.pin_id,
          media_type: "video",
          image_path: media.editText
        } 
        this.ApiService
            .addLinkMedia(data)
            .subscribe(
              media => {
              })
      } else if(media._id) {
        var data:any = {
          media_id: media._id,
          image_path: media.editText
        } 
        this.ApiService
            .addLinkMedia(data)
            .subscribe(
              media => {
                this.loadMedias()
              }, error => {
              })
      }
    } else {
      media.errorMsg = "Please enter valid URL";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, even this is working fine, so i upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can do soething like this. Without doing anything in ts file. You can validate and show validation messages just using form controls.

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
       required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
       [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
     class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>

</div>
```

Taken from angular [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation)

Comment: This would only work if there are form controlls at work... which seems not to be case here.

Comment: In template driven forms you can show validation messages like this. If you are using reactive forms you have to do this in a different way. In the question he's using template driven forms. Thats why I posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the code below and you will realize your mistake. You must add condition that is for the current input only.

```
   <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': form.submitted && !username.valid }">
          <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" required />
          <div *ngIf="form.submitted && !firstName.valid">First Name is required  </div>
  </div>
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': form.submitted && !username.valid }">
          <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="model.lastName" #lastName="ngModel" required />
         <div *ngIf="form.submitted && !lastName.valid" >Last Name is required</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What I meant is that you should have something like this: *ngIf="errorMsg && inputErr[1]"  for 1st input and *ngIf="errorMsg && inputErr[2]" for second input. And then you expand your method with 1 more attribute where you send the index of the input and you make true the wrong inputErr[] index. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Best is you create a custom validator checking your input, you were pointed to the right direction but only very briefly. Create a new directive and provide it in your app module.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appValidURL]',
    providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: URLValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class URLValidatorDirective implements Validator {
    @Input('appValidURL') url: string;

    validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
        return this.url && this.url.startsWith("https://www.youtube.com/embed") ? {value: control.value}}: null;
    }
}
```

Then in your input code use something like this.

```
<input type="text" name="videourl" id="videourl" class="form-control" required appValidURL [(ngModel)]="media.editText">
<div *ngIf="videourl.invalid && (videourl.dirty || videourl.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
   <div *ngIf="videourl.errors.required">
        VideoURL is required!
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="videourl.errors.url">
       It must be an embedded youtube video!
   </div>
</div>
```

I have never used it like this, but it should work maybe with some minor tweeks.

Edit:
This is only for a single input field, your can try tho to use your array names instead of "videourl", not sure how this works out.

Comment: Thanks for response